# Setting JVM MetaSpace

Tags: memory-management, java-8, jvm-arguments

If I read on [Oracle's web site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/considerations.html), they state:

> The amount of native memory that can be used for class metadata is by default unlimited.

But they also write [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html) that:

> MetaSpace is allocated from the same address spaces as the Java heap. Reducing the size of the Java heap will make more space available for MetaSpace. This is only a correct trade-off if there is an excess of free space in the Java heap.

The last sentence seems unclear - I take it as if there is little spare system memory, then reducing the heap size can make more available for MetaSpace(?)

On that assumption, that heap and MetaSpace size limits are independent except that they must both fit into memory, total memory use is then something along the lines of

heap + MetaSpace + threads*stack size + other bits

And setting a limit on total memory use then also involves setting a MetaSpace limit. I understand this will vary, for instance more may be better if codebase is large with lots of classes and that there may not be a definitive answer without profiling..

but what would an initial guideline be - 10% of heap?

Comment: Don’t confuse “address space” with “available RAM”. On a 64 Bit system, there’s more address space than you will (or can) ever use, so the fact that meta space and heap use the same address space is irrelevant. Regarding actual RAM, of course, it can be only in use by either of them at a specific point of time, but that indicates that not playing around with these options is the best strategy to get an adaptive behavior. Don’t try to fix something that isn’t broken.

Comment: That's fine as long as it is small compared to the heap, which I would expect generally if it is class data and cached compiled code. In which case Oracle are a bit confusing as there wouldn't be much of a trade-off. Even so, it is best to set a limit on memory usage in my opinion. And then it is best to have a rough idea about what it should be.